# Query supposed to return 0 but returns 1

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
    COUNT(reservations.personal_information_id) AS returningVisitors,
    (SELECT COUNT(reservations.personal_information_id) FROM reservations) AS totalVisitors,
    ROUND
    (
        (
            COUNT(reservations.personal_information_id)
    *
            100
        )
    /
        (SELECT COUNT(reservations.personal_information_id) FROM reservations)
    ) AS percent
    FROM
        reservations
    GROUP BY
        reservations.personal_information_id
    DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

This Query return

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ returningVisitors totalVisitors percent ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1                 62            2       ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

but is supposed to return

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ returningVisitors totalVisitors percent ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 0                 62            0       ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Does anybody know how to make it so it returns 0 instead of 1?

Comment: You are selecting one row with `LIMIT 1` and returning the `COUNT` of rows. So the count is 1. What are you trying to do that you are expecting 0?

Comment: What database is it?

Comment: Try with `LIMIT 0`...

Comment: @JacobH the limit 1 at the end is there because other wise it returns the same row for about 12-15 times.

Comment: You group by `personal_information_id`, but there is no `personal_information_id` in your selected columns. With the added `LIMIT 1` you say: "give me the result for one `personal_information_id`, but don't tell me which". That doesn't seem to make sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This query really makes no sense. It's impossible to tell what you are trying to do so that we can help you do it. Instead, **please share some sample data, your desired results, and an explanation of how you get those desired results (in words)**. I'm certain we can help you get the SQL you need if we can understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm telling you that selecting 1 row and getting the count of 1 row is going to give you 1. Wishful thinking won't change that! What are you trying to do?

Comment: `GROUP BY reservations.personal_information_id DESC` is no valid SQL by the way. Do you mean `GROUP BY reservations.personal_information_id ORDER BY reservations.personal_information_id  DESC`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . That syntax is permitted in MySQL, so I assume that is the database being used.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: @JacobH - nah, it's actually a completely different reason he's getting the 1.  It's because he's grouping by an ID column and getting a count of the rows for the groupBy.  He's getting 1 because there's only one row in the table with that ID.  The Limit 1 simply says "only return 1 row" - if he omitted it, he'd get back a bunch of rows with '1' in that column.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, instead of telling you, "You need to do X" (because like a comment said, you haven't put enough information in your post to know for sure what you're trying to accomplish) - I'm going to instead say, "This is what your query is doing *currently*", which might help you understand what's going wrong.

First up, here's your general query structure:

```
select
    count(someField),
    ResultOfASubQuery,
    FieldWereGoingToIgnoreForNow
from table
group by columnA
```

That count(someField) doesn't matter - it could be count(otherField) or count(*) - it's going to return the number of records in your groupBy.  So what you're really looking at is:

```
select count(*)
from table
group by columnA
```

... aka, you can expect a row for *each* distinct entry of columnA.  In your case, it's 'personalInformationID' - you're going to get a row for each ID.  If you've got 100 IDs, you're going to get 100 rows  (Almost certainly not what you want.)

Now, when we add the subquery stuff in, it's going to run the subquery for each row.  So your result is going to look something like:

```
Row for ID#1 - 1, CountOfVisitors, DivisionResult
Row for ID#2 - 1, CountOfVisitors, DivisionResult
Row for ID#3 - 1, CountOfVisitors, DivisionResult
Row for ID#4 - 1, CountOfVisitors, DivisionResult
Row - ... etc
```

Why is the first column always '1'?  Because that's what count(*) is giving you for that ID.  There's only one row that matches ID#1.  One row that matches ID#2.  One row that matches ID#3.

Finally, you've got 'Limit 1'.  This doesn't *condense* the data down, it says, "I only want the first row" - aka, the row that corresponds to ID#1.  So your result is:

```
Row for ID#1 - 1, CountOfVisitors, DivisionResult
```

Hopefully that explains what your current version of the query is doing, and why it's not working for you.  Like I mentioned, you haven't really put enough detail in to tell you "Do This", because we don't know what you're trying to do.